# Handle NUL (\0) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, null, oledb

I'm retrieving data from a .xls file using oledb and assigning it to a string variable `Values` using below line:

```
values += "'" + System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(row[i].ToString()) + "',";
```

It woks fine for best case, but if any cell contains the value `\0`, thereafter `values` variable will not update with further values. How can I get rid from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can get rid of null characters from a string really easily:

```
text = text.Replace("\0", "");
```

... but is there any way you can use a prepared statement instead of putting the values directly into the SQL? Or does OLEDB not support that?

Comment: Are C# strings still null delimited, I thought not? Is this an output issue rather than a concatenation issue?

Comment: @Lazarus: In physical representation there *is* a null character at the end of C# strings, but it's only seen by interop. However, you can still have a null character *within* a string, and that can confuse some code, particularly interop code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I will finish your book ;) Then I can stop asking these questions!

Comment: @Lazarus: There's a lot of stuff which *isn't* in the book, you know :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But of course, we all know that the knowledge of Jon Skeet cannot be contained within books as it would need all the wood in the Universe for pulp ;) (excerpt from the Book of Skeet, chapter 2 verse 6).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional operator(condition??true:false) to check whether the coming value is `\0` or not
i just Modify this one as

```
values += "'" + System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(row[i].ToString()!="\0"?row[i].ToString():"") + "',";
```

or you can use this one.

```
values += "'" + System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(row[i].ToString()??"") + "',";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In your first sample code " is needed to \0

Comment: without quote how compiler will recognize `\0` ?